# Docker build cannot fetch 'R.utils'

Tags: r, docker

In my Dockerfile I have the following lines:

```
FROM rocker/verse:latest

RUN R -e "install.packages(c('R.utils'), repos = 'https://cran-archive.r-project.org')"
```

When I run `docker build .` I got:

```
> install.packages(c('R.utils'), repos = 'https://cran-archive.r-project.org')
Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning: unable to access index for repository https://cran-archive.r-project.org/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'https://cran-archive.r-project.org/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Warning message:
package ‘R.utils’ is not available (for R version 4.0.2)
```

I'm new to Docker, not too sure what I'm doing wrong. I put `https://cran-archive.r-project.org/src/contrib/PACKAGES` in browser and it couldn't load, should I try a different repo URL?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try any of the [advertised mirrors](https://cran.r-project.org/mirrors.html), and they should have the most recent release of R.utils for your version of R-4.0.2.

*That* CRAN mirror is specifically for old versions of R. Since your version of R (4.0.2) is not old, it is not found there. That `cran-archive` is intended for R versions without support for those packages (ergo the "archive" label, I suspect).

From the [R FAQ 2.10](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#What-is-CRAN_003f):

> Since March 2016, “old” material is made available from a central CRAN archive server (https://CRAN-archive.R-project.org/).

Or perhaps from the [R for Mac OS X](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/) page:

> Package binaries for R versions older than 3.2.0 are only available from the CRAN archive so users of such versions should adjust the CRAN mirror setting (https://cran-archive.r-project.org) accordingly.

Both of these suggest that `repos = 'https://cran-archive.r-project.org'` should be used for old versions of R, but your error reports R-4.0.2 (not old)

Answer (score 0):

yes, you have to mention the full path to the repo. `https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/R.utils_2.9.2.tar.gz` use this repo link to get R.util.

You can also run the command `sudo apt-get install -y r-cran-r.utils` to install R.utils

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25721884/how-should-i-deal-with-package-xxx-is-not-available-for-r-version-x-y-z-wa